# DOCKER - Airflow How can i Init my postgres scripts in Airflow DB when i docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am testing some stuff where I have to init my Postgres DB DDL into airflow Postgres DB when I compose-up it should automatically init for one time as it will be cached afterward as airflow DB works usually. Thanks

Comment: Are you putting your own tables in the Airflow DB next to the Airflow tables, or are you connecting to another Postgres DB?

Comment: i want to put my tables next to airflow tables

Comment: Airflow itself also does some init-processing on its database when started in Docker-compose. So, it might be better to create an extra container with a new Postgres database.

Comment: do you have any kind of example for this kind of work, actually I want to use airflow DB so that we don't have to run manual init every time and whenever docker-composes up for the first time we all scripts automatically loaded up in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works and init your scripts when you docker composed up.

pro TIP:
If you want to add more files and you have already init the airflow DB or your DB what you can do is **docker-compose down --volume** what this will do will automatically remove all the data in the data directory. and for init to work **Postgres data directory have to be empty**

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:13

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow

    ports: 
    - "5432:5432"

    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /path/to/my/host/folder/filename.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/filename.sql

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the last comment: Adding your own database to the Airflow Docker-compose file:

Put this piece of code as a service somewhere amongst the other services:

```yaml
  mypostgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: mydbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: securepassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
    restart: always
```

Make sure you have a database-directory and a init-database.sh file in the current directory (otherwise the volume mappings fail)

Comment: So you are creating 2 database In a single container does this work?

Comment: Moreover  is shell script empty

Comment: A docker-compose file creates more than 1 container. What this solution does is add an extra container to the collection of containers started by this docker-compose file. 
The shell script is indeed empty, you can add the commends to do your initialisation on the database.